# Error running JCuda app in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, cuda, parallel-processing

I'm a new JCuda user and I started to try some samples in my node.
I'm running a simple:

```
import jcuda.*;
import jcuda.runtime.*;
public class JCudaRuntimeTest{
     public static void main(String args[]){
         Pointer pointer = new Pointer();
         JCuda.cudaMalloc(pointer, 4);
         System.out.println("Pointer: "+pointer);
         JCuda.cudaFree(pointer);
     }
}
```

I put every library in the same folder and a can easily compile the code, but when I run `java JCudaRuntimeTest`, I got this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jcuda/Pointer
    at JCudaRuntimeTest.main(JCudaRuntimeTest.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jcuda.Pointer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 1 more
```

suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` almost always means that something is missing from your classpath.

Make sure the `jcuda-<version>.jar` file (as well as possibly other necessary JAR files) are on the classpath when you run your program.

You can specify the classpath when you run your program with the `-cp` switch, for example:

```
java -cp C:\Project\jcuda\jcuda-0.3.2a.jar;C:\Project\mystuff\classes org.mystuff.MyProgram
```

or by setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable (not recommended).

Comment: Exactly, but I'm compiling using `javac -cp C:\Project\jcuda\jcuda-0.3.2a.jar`.
But I can't figure out with jcuda/Pointer is throwing exception, maybe wrong version or something?

Comment: @Luis You need to specify the classpath not only when compiling, but also when running the program. The classes from the JAR are not linked in statically at compile time.

Comment: Ok, but specifying the cuda.jar when running the program I got the `NoClassDefFoundError` again, I start to think that is more simple problem. Can you type exactly the commnand expected to run properly? I'm typing `mdantas@BOPE:~/jCUDA/examples$ java -cp ../jcuda.jar LoadModule`

Comment: You also have to specify the directory that contains your own class files in the classpath. For example: `java -cp ..\jcuda-0.3.2a.jar;. LoadModule` Note the `.` to include the current directory in the classpath. Use \ instead of `/` on Windows to navigate directories.